# If $\gcd ( a, b) = 1$ and $a \equiv b$ mod $n $, then $\gcd (a, n) = 1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to show that for $a,b,n \in \mathbb{Z}$, if $\gcd ( a, b) = 1$ and $a \equiv b$ mod $n $, then $\gcd (a, n) = 1$. My attempt is as follows:

Given : $\gcd (a, b) =1 \implies \exists x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a*x + b * y = 1$.

I got $b= \frac{(1 - (a*x))}{y}$.

Substituting this in $a \equiv b$ mod $n $, I got $a * (x + y) \equiv 1 $ mod $n$.

However, I am not able to proceed further as I do not know how to show that $\gcd (x+y,a) =1$.

Comment: Any common factor of $a$ and $n$ divides $a+kn$ for any $k$, and is therefore a common factor of $a$ and $a+kn$.

Comment: By the linked dupe $\,1=(a,b) = (a,b\!-\!a) = (\color{#c00}{a,n}\frac{b-a}n)\Rightarrow 1 = (\color{#c00}{a,n})\ \ $

Comment: Or: $\ \color{#c00}{n\mid a\!-\!b}\Rightarrow (a,\color{#c00}n)\mid (a,\color{#c00}{a\!-\!b})=(a,b)\,$ by the 3rd & 1st dupes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $ax+by=1$ and $a-b=kn$ for some integers $x,y,k$.

Then $ax+ (a-kn)y=1$, i.e. $a(x+y) + (-k)n=1$.

Thus each common divisor of $a$ and $n$ is a divisor of $1$ and hence $(a,n)=1$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).